# Custom a MATLAB 11 activex code (for creating an MS-Word 2007 document) to MATLAB 2015 and MS-Word 2010

Tags: matlab, ms-word, activex

I wrote the next code to create a Word document with figures arranged in a couple of tables. It works perfectly on my laptop with MATLAB 2011 and MS-Word 2007. However when I try to run it on the university computer with MATLAB 2015 and MS-Word 2010 the resulting document is screwed up. Can someone show me how to fix it? and how I can write a program, which is platform independent?

```
function finalWriteToWord

    WordFileName='MyTestDoc2.doc';
    CurDir=pwd;
    FileSpec = fullfile(CurDir,WordFileName);
    if exist(FileSpec,'file')
        delete(FileSpec)
    end
    word_server=actxserver('Word.Application');
    word_document=invoke(word_server.Documents,'Add');
    CM_IN_POINTS=28.3464567;         %1cm=28.3464567
    word_document.Pagesetup.LeftMargin=0.7*CM_IN_POINTS;
    word_document.Pagesetup.RightMargin=0.7*CM_IN_POINTS;
    word_document.Pagesetup.TopMargin=0.5*CM_IN_POINTS;
    word_document.Pagesetup.BottomMargin=0.5*CM_IN_POINTS;


    for table_ind=1:3
        nr_rows_p=4;
        nr_cols_p=2;
        range=word_document.Content;
        range.Collapse(0);
        table=invoke(word_document.Tables,'add',range,nr_rows_p,nr_cols_p,1,0);
        %write the data into the table
        for row_ind=1:nr_rows_p
            for col_ind=1:nr_cols_p
                    fig=figure;plot([1:10]);title(['Figure: table-' num2str(table_ind)  ' row-' num2str(row_ind) ' col-' num2str(col_ind)]);xlabel('Time [s]');ylabel('Amplitude [A]')  
                    print(fig,'-dmeta');
                    table.Cell(row_ind,col_ind).Select;
                    invoke(word_server.Selection,'Paste');
                    numShapes=word_document.InlineShapes.Count;
                    word_document.InlineShapes.Item(numShapes).Height=98;
                    word_document.InlineShapes.Item(numShapes).Width=270;
            end
        end
        word_server.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment='wdAlignParagraphCenter'; 
        %word_server.Selection.InsertBreak; %pagebreak
    end

    CloseWord(word_server,word_document,FileSpec);    
    close all;
return

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

function CloseWord(actx_word_p,word_handle_p,word_file_p)

    invoke(word_handle_p,'SaveAs',word_file_p,1);

    % Close the word window:
    invoke(word_handle_p,'Close');            
    % Quit MS Word
    invoke(actx_word_p,'Quit');            
    % Close Word and terminate ActiveX:
    delete(actx_word_p);            
return

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: How exactly is the document getting "screwed up"?

Comment: The figures that should be in tables 1 and 2 are not shown. Only table 3 is shown and instead of showing the entire table in one page, it shows enlarged cells such that each row is shown in a different page and also the figures that should be in the cells are enlarged, and as a result are only partly shown. After the last row of table 3 there are 8 empty rows.

Comment: I just wanted to add that on my laptop the resulting document contains 3 tables of 2 columns and 4 rows. Each table occupies an entire page and contains 8 figures.